# Draw a tRNA diagram

Tags: diagrams

I am new to TeX. I want to draw a figure with many [tRNA secondary structure](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikibooks/en/thumb/3/3f/TRNA.png/350px-TRNA.png) 
Which packages to use to draw the tRNA itself? Are there any guides or tutorials?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: I didn't ask to draw it I just need a guide or tutorial for the package that could do it which I don't know @MartinSchröder

Comment: Fair enough. Sorry.

Comment: You can use any tool you like to do the drawing so long as it can export to some form that TeX can include (which is more or less anything, but PDF is probably preferable).

Comment: any tool like ? @Thruston

Comment: If you want to draw things interactively: Inkscape, Dia, Omnigraffle, Adobe Illustrator, [etc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_vector_graphics_editors).  Or you can use the more TeX-like mark-up languages, like Metapost, TikZ, PSTricks. The trade off is usually between time to learn the tool and quality of output.  (But this is a long discussion...)

Comment: You might ask [this guy](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/13542/orientations-of-codon-and-anticodon) how he drew his diagram.

Comment: But there seem to be many specialist tools out there, [for example](http://varna.lri.fr/index.php?lang=en&page=home&css=varna), which could output to formats you could include in TeX.